# How to get indices of a Mat with specific value?

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to find indices of an array that equal with specific value. so i've Written this code:

```
vector<int> _classes = { 2,2,1,1,3,3,3,3,5,5,4,4,5,6,6 };
vector<int> labelVec = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

vector<int> index;

for (int i = 0; i < labelVec.size(); i++)
{
    compare(_classes, labelVec[i], index, CMP_EQ);
    std::vector<int>::iterator nn = find(index.begin(), index.end(), 255);
}
```

but i have this error : `Unhandled exception at 0x760B5608 in compareFuncTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x004DDC44.` if i define `index` as `Mat`, this problem will be resolved. but if i define `index` as `Mat`, i can't use from `find()`. also in this [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#compare) states: output array (in my code as `index`) that has the same size and type as the input arrays. PLZ help me to fix this code.

Comment: And what does your debugger tell you about the stack trace and variable values leading up to that exception?

Comment: I edited my code.

Comment: Saeid, why are you doing this comparison? you can do the find directly with the standard vectors. Also, cv::Mat has iterators and you can do begin and end (it is templated) and use the find with a cv mat

Comment: @api55 How can i find directly with the standard vectors?

Comment: @api55 thanks, but i want indices and not values. With your advice, i wrote this code: `std::vector<int>::iterator nn = std::find(_classes.begin(), _classes.end(), labelVec[i]);`     `cout << nn - _classes.begin() + 1 << endl;` but this code get me only first index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still do not get what is the point of this test, I guess this will be in some other algorithm... So, I give you two possible solutions.

1) Without OpenCV

First, you must know that

```
std::vector<int>::iterator nn = find(index.begin(), index.end(), 255);
```

Will only give you the first occurrance. Knowing this, here is a way you could check if the label is inside the `_classes` vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{

  std::vector<int> _classes = { 2,2,1,1,3,3,3,3,5,5,4,4,5,6,6 };
  std::vector<int> labelVec = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

  for (const auto& label: labelVec)
  {    
    std::vector<int>::iterator nn = find(_classes.begin(), _classes.end(), label);
    if (nn != _classes.end())
    {
      std::cout << "I got the value from _classes: " << *nn << std::endl;
    } else 
    {
        std::cout << "I couldn't find the value with label:" << label << std::endl;
    }

  }
}
```

Here I iterate over all the labels (as you did) and then use the find directly in the classes, but with the label variable. Then I check if I found the label or not, if not, it will give you a value equal to `_classes.end()` which will give error if you try to use it (look at the extra label 7 which is not found).
This example can be tested [here](http://cpp.sh/4tafe) online.

2) With OpenCV

no oline test here. But this one is also easy to do. If you have a Mat in index you will only need to change the iterators to be templated. Like this:

```
auto nn = find(index.begin<int>(), index.end<int>(), 255);
```

If you a cv::Mat of classes you can also do it as in the method before and skip the comparison part (this would be faster)

## Update

Since you want is the indices and all of them, then you have to iterate over it :/ if you wanted the values you could have used copy_if. You can create a lambda function to easily do the job.

like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  auto getIndices = [](const std::vector<int>& vec, const int value){
      std::vector<int> result;
      for (size_t t = 0; t < vec.size(); t++)
      {
          if (vec[t] == value)
          {
              result.push_back(static_cast<int>(t));
          }
      }
      return result;
  };
  std::vector<int> _classes = { 2,2,1,1,3,3,3,3,5,5,4,4,5,6,6 };
  std::vector<int> labelVec = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

  for (const auto& label: labelVec)
  {    
    std::vector<int> nn = getIndices(_classes, label);

    std::cout << "I got the following indices for value"<< label<< ": [ ";
    for (const auto& n : nn)
    {
        std::cout << n << ",";
    }
    std::cout << " ]" << std::endl;

  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i want indices and not values. With your advice, i wrote this code: `std::vector<int>::iterator nn = std::find(_classes.begin(), _classes.end(), labelVec[i]);`    `cout << nn - _classes.begin() + 1 << endl;` but this code get me only first index.

Comment: @Saeid it is recommended to use std::distance instead of the substraction. As I told you before, find, only gives you 1 value. You could have used the std::copy_if if you wanted the values, but since you want to have the index, then a loop should do it...